# Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed Runtime.ExitError

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, runtime-error, out-of-memory

My task is insert 29 million rows to AWS RDS Postgrest Db.
I insert 200 rows one time.
I use Lambda with trigger is AWS SQS

My Lambda run normal, but when inserted 57000 rows, it crahsed with this error
"Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed
Runtime.ExitError"

[This is log when lambda succes, Max Memory used is : 549 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlePW.png)

[But nearest time, Max memory used is full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUOcp.png)

Can u guys tell me what issue i get here? Thank kiu so much